# How to return the string that failed regex with RegularExpressionAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, model-view-controller

I have written regex that works and I return the ErrorMessage for the user to see.
In my case i am validating an array of strings (emails), and I want the user to know what field failed and not just a generic message. Is there a way to return the string that failed?

I could write my own regex handling system that would loop through the strings and return the ones that failed the regex.
It does feel a little wrong though, since .net gives me the ability to do regex on my models.

Maybe I have mistaken the functionality of model regex, if it fails. it fails. And I can just know what model failed, not what particular object.

I have looked through the documentation on:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2

I can however not find any option to return the object. But might have overlooked it.

```
    [Display(Name = "Admin Emails")]

    [RegularExpression(@"[a-z0-9!#$%&' * +/=?^ _`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0- 
    9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0- 
    9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?",

    ErrorMessage = "Admin needs a valid email")]

    public List<string> AdminEmails { get; set; }
```

and my controller just checks the model

```
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
```

what I want is the Error message to return something like "admin@admin needs to be a valid email"

Comment: Are you sure that attribute will loop over a list of strings and apply to each one? I would assume it will cast or ToString() the object and run the regexp on that.

Comment: Oh... yeah. You are correct, I see now that the regex fails. It worked for a single string so I just assumed it applied to all elements in the list... Now, how do I make it do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if we made a custom attribute doing this as the following :

```
 public class EmailsCustomAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public EmailsCustomAttribute(string pattern)
        {
            this.Pattern = pattern;
        }

        public string Pattern { get; }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex(Pattern);
            List<string> emails = value as List<string>;
            string errorMessage = string.Empty;
            foreach (var item in emails)
            {
                if (!regex.IsMatch(item))
                {
                    errorMessage += this.ErrorMessage.Replace("{0}", item);
                }
            }
            ValidationResult validationResult = new ValidationResult(errorMessage);

            return validationResult;
        }
    }
```

and use it as the following  :

```
public class TestModel
    {
        [EmailsCustom(@"[a-z0-9!#$%&' * +/=?^ _`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0- 
    9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0- 
    9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", ErrorMessage = "{0} is invalid email")]
        public List<string> Emails { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: This works great! Thanks a lot!
I had to change the regex a little as the one I had was slightly wrong.

and i added a white space to error message to separate several wrong emails.
**ErrorMessage = " {0} is invalid email"**

What would be even more awesome is if I could make the ErrorMessage an array if several emails are wrong. But i don't think that is possible as I think the ErrorMessage is a single string.

Comment: you are welcome , we can add a separator and split them after that when needed , what do u think ?